# How to change the parameter of hook in react (fetch hook)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My fetch hook:

```
  import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useOurApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(initialData);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;

    const handleFetchResponse = response => {
      if (unmounted) return initialData;

      setHasError(!response.ok);
      setIsLoading(false);
      return response.ok && response.json ? response.json() : initialData;
    };

    const fetchData = () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      return fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
        .then(handleFetchResponse)
        .catch(handleFetchResponse);
    };

    if (initialUrl && !unmounted)
      fetchData().then(data => !unmounted && setFetchedData(data));

    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  }, [url]);

  return { isLoading, hasError, setUrl, data: fetchedData };
};
```

I call this hook in a function like so:

```
//states
    const [assignments, setAssignments] = useState([])
    const [submissions, setSubmissions] = useState([])
    const [bulk_edit, setBulk_edit]     = useState(false)
    const [ENDPOINT_URL, set_ENDPOINT_URL]  = useState('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1')

    let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1';
    const { data, isLoading, hasError } = useOurApi(ENDPOINT_URL, []);
```

My question is how can I call this instance of userOurAPI with a different URL. I have tried calling it within a function where I need it but we can't call hooks within functions, so I am not sure how to pass it new url to get new data. I don't want to have many instances of userOurAPI because that is not DRY. Or is this not possible? New to hooks, so go easy on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the URL such that the component updates and fetches new data, you create a set function that changes the URL and you make sure that the useEffect() is run again on the change of URL. Return your setter function for URL so that you can use it outside of the first instance of your hook. In my code, you will see that I return a setUrl, I can use that to update fetch! Silly of me not to notice, but hopefully this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do it the way you chose to, but there are other ways of working around such a problem.

One other way would be to always re-fetch whenever the URL changes, without an explicit setter returned from the hook. This would look something like this:

```
export const useOurApi = (url, initialData) => { // URL passed directly through removes the need for a specific internal url `useState`
  // const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl); // No longer used

  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    // Handle fetch
  }, [url]);

  return { isLoading, hasError, data: fetchedData }; // No more `setUrl`
};
```

This may not always be what you want though, sometimes you may not want to re-fetch all the data on every url change, for example if the URL is empty, you may not want to update the url. In that case you could just add a `useEffect` to the `useOurApi` custom hook to update the internal url and re-fetch:

```
export const useOurApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);

  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    // Handle fetch
  }, [url]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... do some permutation to the URL or validate it
    setUrl(initialUrl);
  }, [initialUrl]);

  return { isLoading, hasError, data: fetchedData }; // No more `setUrl`
};
```

If you still sometimes want to re-fetch the data, unrelated to the URL, you could output some function from the hook to trigger the data fetching. Something like this:

```
export const useOurApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(initialData);

  const refetch = useCallback(() => {
    // Your fetch logic
  }, [url]);

  useEffect(() => {
    refetch(); // In case you still want to automatically refetch the data on url change
  }, [url]);

  return { isLoading, hasError, refetch, data: fetchedData };
};
```

Now you can call `refetch` whenever you want to trigger the re-fetching. You may still want to be able to internally change the url, but this gives you another a bit more flexible access to the fetching and when it occurs.

Answer (score -1):

you confuse the difference between **simple function** and **function component**
**Function Component** are not just simple function. It means that the have to return a component or a html tag

I think you should turn four function to simple function like so

```
export const useOurApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
    let url = initialUrl, fetchedData = initialData, 
        isLoading= true, hasError = false, unmounted = false;

    const handleFetchResponse = response => {
        if (unmounted) return initialData;

        hasError = !response.ok;
        isLoading = false;
        return response.ok && response.json ? response.json() : initialData;
    };

    const fetchData = () => {
        isLoading = true;
        return fetch(url, { credentials: 'include' })
            .then(handleFetchResponse)
            .catch(handleFetchResponse);
    };

    if (initialUrl && !unmounted)
        fetchData().then(data => {
            if(!unmounted) fetchedData =data;
            unmounted = true;
        });

    return { isLoading, hasError, url, data: fetchedData };
};
```

Comment: So it is just a one time use function, we can't ever update its parameters? ( I am referring to the hook function)

Comment: I said that react hook are not just simple funstions, so you con't call them as you wrote

Comment: Sorry, I meant, how can I update its parameter (url)

Comment: as normal parameter by assigning another value to it. You should consider that your **useOurApi** function is a normal function and then just refactor it in consequence.